# Why has the link color changed like that?

Tags: html, css, inheritance, colors

I saw the below code on the [Mozilla site on the section explaining the inheritance in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance#Understanding_inheritance)

I understand why the first two link colors are blue and green, however why does the third one change color to black and the fourth one to green? I think I don't really understand the purpose of initial and unset attributes nor the difference between them and the explanation on the Mozilla site is enigmatic to me. Can someone please explain this to me?

```css
body {
  color: green;
}

.my-class-1 a {
  color: inherit;
}

.my-class-2 a {
  color: initial;
}

.my-class-3 a {
  color: unset;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Default <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
  <li class="my-class-1">Inherit the <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
  <li class="my-class-2">Reset the <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
  <li class="my-class-3">Unset the <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: unset is equivalent to inherit for color and initial is the initial value set for color (most of the case black)

Comment: **inherit**: Get the property from the parent element.
**initial**: The default value for the property (the browser default).
**unset**: Acts as either inherit or initial. It’ll act as inherit if the parent has a value that matches, or else it will act as initial.

Comment: 3rd one is black because it takes the initial browser default value and 4th one is green as in this case unset acts as inherit because there is a parent with a matching value.

Comment: @Debs initial is not the browser default but the default value specified by the specification

Comment: @TemaniAfif So isn't the default link color blue? Why does it change to black then?

Comment: the default color set by the browser for links is blue and initial doesn't consider this, it consider the intial value set by the specification and it's black. If you use `display:initial` with `div` you will see that the div will inline and not block even if the default value set by the browser for div is block BUT the initial value for display is inline